# Generalized Stochastic Matrices with Negative Transition Probabilities

Tags: probability, matrices, reference-request, markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

Consider a square matrix $A$ with the property $\sum_j A_{ij}=1$ for all $i$. That is, I've relaxed the positive element requirement for a (right) stochastic matrix. What properties do these matrices have?

It appears that provided the eigenvalues $\{\lambda_j\}$ of $A$ all have $|\lambda_j|\leq 1$ a Markov chain consisting of application of $A^k$ to some quasiprobability vector $\vec v$ with $\sum_j v_j=1$ should converge to a stationary distribution.

Do such matrices have a name in the mathematical literature? Are there results on convergence and mixing times of such generalized Markov chains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more than $\ |\lambda_j|\le1\ $ to get convergence of $\ A^k\ $. If
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&-1&2\\
0&0&1}\ ,
$$
for instance, the eigenvalues of $\ A\ $ are $\ 1,-1\ $ and $\ 1\ $, but $\ A^k=A\ $ for $\ k\ $ odd and $\ A^k\ $ is the $\ 3\times3\ $ identity matrix for $\ k\ $ even.

**Addendum**

In general
$$
A^k=E\,\pmatrix{\Lambda_1^k&0&\dots&0\\0&\Lambda_2^k&\dots&0\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&\dots&\Lambda_r^k}\,E^{-1}\ ,
$$
where each $\ \Lambda_j\ $ is a [Jordan block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix) corresponding to eigenvalue $\ \lambda_j\ $, and $\ E\ $ is a matrix whose columns are [generalised eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector) of $\ A\ $.  The Jordan block $\ \Lambda_j^k\ $  will converge as $\ k\rightarrow\infty\ $ if and only if either:

- $\ \big|\,\lambda_j\,\big|<1\ $; or
- $\ \lambda_j=1\ $ and $\ \Lambda_j\ $ is a $\ 1\times1\ $ block.

Therefore, $\ A^k\ $ will converge as $\ k\rightarrow\infty\ $ if and only if every one of its Jordan blocks satisfies one of these two conditions.